# Best way to add On Sale link in top navigation

Tags: sales, menu, navigation

I'm wondering if there is a correct way (or best) way to implement this. I would like there to be a link in the top menu navigation that, when clicked, will bring users to our "on-sale" page.

We currently mark things "on-sale" using magento's special price fields.

The way I currently have it setup is like this:

I created a category called "Sale" which put a link into the top nav.

in the URL key I put in "sale"

I then went to the Catalog>URL Rewrite Management and changed the "requested path" to "/sale"

This is currently working, although I don't know if it's the best way to have done this. Please let me know your thoughts and thanks in advance!

This is the site: http://bit.ly/1iv22yg

Answer (score 1):

For me this seems like a good idea.

It means that you can achieve what you are looking for without having to write custom code, which should save you development time and money. It will also allow for the admin user to easily move items into the `Sale` category easily using the core Magento functionality.